# Python different log level for outputfile an terminal

Tags: python, logging, log-level

Is there a way, without using an external module, to set the logging level for terminal output to info, and the logging level for writing a *.log to warning?

Why do I ask?
I have a script that will run over a long period of time. Therefore I want to see in the terminal that my code is still running, but don't want to get all the info stuff inside the *.log file. Only if the logging level is 30 or higher it should print to my logging file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty standard logging configuration. Just create a logger and add a streamhandler with info level and a filehandler with error level.

```
import logging

fh = logging.FileHandler('logs.txt')
fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(sh)

logger.info('this is only on console')
logger.error('this is in file too')
```

Comment: Every beginning is small and trivial. Thank you for your fast answer. And the little example.